# where do I put configs in a angularjs app?

Tags: angularjs, git, configuration, hardcoded

In my angular app, I have a URL to which I connect for retrieving some data, a CORS enabled server.

Now, so far I had it hardcoded in my javascript file:

```
server_url = "http://localhost:7888/api.php/json?id=2"
```

Now, on test and production, those URLs of course are not valid...and everytime I do a `git pull` it overrides my customizations.

Where would I elegantly put a config like that in an angular app?

Comment: what do you use on your backend?

Comment: I think this could be done by a mix of your middleware and your front end, look at the meanjs.org approach, http://meanjs.org/generator.html#overview

Comment: You might want to see about using something like Grunt to add the URL to your JS depending on the environment.

Comment: @jack.the.ripper it's a plain php/apache2 web app

Comment: are you able to do a simple php print over your index file?

Comment: ? why that @jack.the.ripper

Comment: actually you can write the URL to your constant variable in angular from PHP depending on "your environment", if you like that approach I can elaborate a little bit more in an answer

Comment: Well if you are inclined and can spare the time it's always cool to learn smth new, so you're kindly invited to provide an answer with that approach :) might also be useful to someone else

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as a constant. Assuming you have an app named `App`:

`angular.module('App', []).constant("urls", {"server_url":"http://localhost:7888/api.php/json?id=2"});`

Once declared as a constant, you'd inject it as a dependency, just as you would a service.

Comment: how do you override it depending on the target environment?

Comment: Don't inject it and declare a new value.

Comment: you can inject the url no harm on that, but that url eventually will change depending on the target environment, you still can inject it but using a different value

Comment: @TheHeadRush you mean declaring multiple constants, for each environment one?

Comment: Kinda. You can declare multiple values in the same constant object. For example if you have multiple endpoints, you could do something like:

`angular.module('App', []).constant("urls",` `{"server_url":"http://localhost:7888/",`
`"endpoint1":"api.php/json?id=1",`
`"endpoint2":"api.php/json?id=2"});`

Answer (score 0):

well, basically I'd adopt a mean.js approach here, it's quite easy to implement and it could be useful to you or anybody else.

you have to write from your middleware into your main HTML file in angular (ex: [index.html](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/app/views/layout.server.view.html)), in your case the URL for your endpoint have to change depending on your environment just to keep it simple let's say we have dev (localhost) and production (mydomain.com)

in your index html do a simple write:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php 
         if(strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'mydomain.com') !== false){
             print "var endpoint = '"+ $server_url+ "';" 
         } else{
            print "var endpoint = '"+ $local_url+ "';" 
         }

         ?>
    </script>
```

one you got that into your main index.html it's available in angular by using the window object, so you can wrap it into a constant or a [service](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/c93101202f7c63d60ad7bd890604892a704f78f6/public/modules/users/services/authentication.client.service.js).

this is the example for a constant:

```
angular.module('app').run(function () {

}).value('endpoint', window.endpoint);
```

> I'm not fluent in PHP, but I hope you can get my point